# Unable to place order from Magento Admin, showing error on city field required

Tags: magento-1, address, admin-order-create

I am unable to place order from admin. I enter all the data in required field. When I place order, error showing in the City field - this is a required field. I am using magento 1.9.3.7 version

can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please can you give us more details about installed modules and admin edits? That is not the default position for City in that form. It is supposed to be between Street Address and Country, so I suppose you are using a customization.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using this module http://www.magebuzz.com/region-city-manager.html . I think this module  cause city field error

Comment: @Aks Some questions:
**#1**: Are there any specific Validation Rules introduced by this module in terms of this Field? (Have you tried to update those?)
**#2**: If **#1** is YES: Are you sure that the City you were entering does not contain characters that are not allowed?

Comment: @Aks let me know if you have any issue related to this.

Comment: @Aks, Is that resolved your issue?

Comment: @kunj, Yes code worked. Thank you so much for sharing your valuable knowledge and experience to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Aks, Welcome, happy to help you even I learned new from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

You need to change in some file for this:

In this `app/code/local/Magebuzz/Improvedaddress/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Renderer/City.php` file, you need to update some code, you can either override or update in this file because this is a bug:

Current `public function render` function :

```
public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $country = $element->getForm()->getElement('country_id');
                $region = $element->getForm()->getElement('region_id');
        if (!is_null($region)) {
            $regionId = $region->getValue();
        } else {
            return $element->getDefaultHtml();
        }

        $cityId = $element->getForm()->getElement('city_id')->getValue();
        $quoteStoreId = $element->getEntityAttribute()->getStoreId();

        $html = '<tr>';
        $element->setClass('input-text');
        $element->setRequired(true);
        $html .= '<td class="label">' . $element->getLabelHtml() . '</td><td class="value">';
        $html .= $element->getElementHtml();

        $selectName = str_replace('city', 'city_id', $element->getName());
        $selectId = $element->getHtmlId() . '_id';
        $html .= '<select id="' . $selectId . '" name="' . $selectName
            . '" class="select required-entry" style="display:none">';
        $html .= '<option value="">' . $this->_factory->getHelper('customer')->__('Please select') . '</option>';
        $html .= '</select>';

        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n";
        $html .= '$("' . $selectId . '").setAttribute("defaultValue", "' . $cityId.'");' . "\n";
        $html .= 'new CityUpdater("' . $country->getHtmlId() . '", "' . $region->getHtmlId() . '", "' . $element->getHtmlId() . '", "' .
            $selectId . '", ' . Mage::helper('improvedaddress')->getCityJson().');' . "\n";
        $html .= '</script>' . "\n";

        $html .= '</td></tr>' . "\n";

        return $html;
    }
```

Update `public function render` function :

```
public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $country = $element->getForm()->getElement('country_id');
                $region = $element->getForm()->getElement('region_id');
        if (!is_null($region)) {
            $regionId = $region->getValue();
        } else {
            return $element->getDefaultHtml();
        }

        $cityId = $element->getForm()->getElement('city_id')->getValue();
        $quoteStoreId = $element->getEntityAttribute()->getStoreId();

        $html = '<tr>';
        $element->setClass('input-text');
        $element->setRequired(true);
        $html .= '<td class="label">' . $element->getLabelHtml() . '</td><td class="value">';
        $html .= $element->getElementHtml();

        $selectName = str_replace('city', 'city_id', $element->getName());
        $selectId = $element->getHtmlId() . '_id';
        $html .= '<select id="' . $selectId . '" name="' . $selectName
            . '" class="select required-entry" style="display:none" disabled="disabled">';
        $html .= '<option value="">' . $this->_factory->getHelper('customer')->__('Please select') . '</option>';
        $html .= '</select>';

        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n";
        $html .= '$("' . $selectId . '").setAttribute("defaultValue", "' . $cityId.'");' . "\n";
        $html .= 'new CityUpdater("' . $country->getHtmlId() . '", "' . $region->getHtmlId() . '", "' . $element->getHtmlId() . '", "' .
            $selectId . '", ' . Mage::helper('improvedaddress')->getCityJson().');' . "\n";
        $html .= '</script>' . "\n";

        $html .= '</td></tr>' . "\n";

        return $html;
    }
```

I have updated this code from `$html .= '<select id="' . $selectId . '" name="' . $selectName
                . '" class="select required-entry" style="display:none">';` To `$html .= '<select id="' . $selectId . '" name="' . $selectName
                . '" class="select required-entry" style="display:none" disabled="disabled">';` in that function.

Now you need to update this `js/magebuzz/improvedaddress.js` file in `update: function() {` function :

Current code in that JS:

```
update: function() {
        if (this.cities[this.regionEl.value]) {
            var i, option, city, def;
            def = this.citySelectEl.getAttribute('defaultValue');
            if (this.cityTextEl) {
                if (!def) {
                    def = this.cityTextEl.value.toLowerCase();
                }
                ////need to comment this to avoid issue when saving address without touching city field
                //this.cityTextEl.value = '';
            }

            this.citySelectEl.options.length = 1;
            for (cityId in this.cities[this.regionEl.value]) {
                city = this.cities[this.regionEl.value][cityId];

                option = document.createElement('OPTION');
                option.value = city.code;
                option.text = city.name.stripTags();
                option.title = city.name;

                if (this.citySelectEl.options.add) {
                    this.citySelectEl.options.add(option);
                } else {
                    this.citySelectEl.appendChild(option);
                }               

                if (cityId==def || (city.name && city.name==def) ||
                        (city.name && city.code.toLowerCase()==def)
                ) {
                    this.citySelectEl.value = city.code;
                }
            }

            if (this.cityTextEl) {
                this.cityTextEl.style.display = 'none';
            }
            this.citySelectEl.style.display = '';
        }
        else {
            this.citySelectEl.options.length = 1;
            if (this.cityTextEl) {
                this.cityTextEl.style.display = '';
            }
            this.citySelectEl.style.display = 'none';
            Validation.reset(this.citySelectEl);
        }
    }
```

Updated that `update` function:

```
update: function() {
        if (this.cities[this.regionEl.value]) {
            var i, option, city, def;
            def = this.citySelectEl.getAttribute('defaultValue');
            if (this.cityTextEl) {
                if (!def) {
                    def = this.cityTextEl.value.toLowerCase();
                }
                ////need to comment this to avoid issue when saving address without touching city field
                //this.cityTextEl.value = '';
            }

            this.citySelectEl.options.length = 1;
            for (cityId in this.cities[this.regionEl.value]) {
                city = this.cities[this.regionEl.value][cityId];

                option = document.createElement('OPTION');
                option.value = city.code;
                option.text = city.name.stripTags();
                option.title = city.name;

                if (this.citySelectEl.options.add) {
                    this.citySelectEl.options.add(option);
                } else {
                    this.citySelectEl.appendChild(option);
                }               

                if (cityId==def || (city.name && city.name==def) ||
                        (city.name && city.code.toLowerCase()==def)
                ) {
                    this.citySelectEl.value = city.code;
                }
            }

            if (this.cityTextEl) {
                this.cityTextEl.style.display = 'none';
            }
            this.citySelectEl.style.display = '';
            this.citySelectEl.disabled = '';
        }
        else {
            this.citySelectEl.options.length = 1;
            if (this.cityTextEl) {
                this.cityTextEl.style.display = '';
            }
            this.citySelectEl.disabled = true;
            this.citySelectEl.style.display = 'none';
            Validation.reset(this.citySelectEl);
        }
    }
```

After the changes, it will disable that select so you can submit form without hidden fields validation. Let me know you face any issue related to this.